# My weather data is not showing up in my view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I can't figure out why my view controller is not showing the data, even though I can see it in the output window.

Output:

```
Muḩāfaz̧at Al Jīzah

Clear

88.0
```

my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadCurrentWeather = currentWeatherData()
    loadCurrentWeather.downloadWeatherData {
        //setting uo UI to download data
        self.updateTodayUI()
    }
}

func updateTodayUI() {
    locationLabel.text = loadCurrentWeather.cityName
    weatherTypeLabel.text = loadCurrentWeather.weatherType
    currentTempLabel.text = "\(loadCurrentWeather.currentTemp)"
    weatherTypeImage.image = UIImage(named: loadCurrentWeather.weatherType)
}
```

My view controller in Xcode:

[image: screen in xcode]

My view controller on iphone:

[image: screen on iphone]

currentweatherData the code where I'm downloading the data form.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class currentWeatherData {
    var cityNameone: String!
    var dateone: String!
    var weatherTypeone: String!
    var currentTempone: Double!

    var cityName: String {
        if cityNameone == nil {
            cityNameone = ""
        }
        return cityNameone
    }

    var date: String {
        if dateone == nil {
            dateone = ""
        }
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
        let currentDate = dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
        self.dateone = "Today, \(currentDate)"
        return dateone
    }

    var weatherType: String{
        if weatherTypeone == nil{
            weatherTypeone = ""
        }
        return weatherTypeone
    }

    var currentTemp: Double {
        if currentTempone == nil {
            currentTempone = 0.0
        }
        return currentTempone
    }

    func downloadWeatherData(completed: DownloadComplete){
        // to tell alamofire where to download the data
        let weatherURL = URL (string: currentWeatherURL)!
        Alamofire.request(weatherURL).responseJSON{ response in
            let result = response.result

            if let dictionary = result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{
                if let name = dictionary["name"] as? String {
                    self.cityNameone = name.capitalized
                    print(self.cityNameone ?? "No city name")
                }

                if let weather = dictionary["weather"] as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]{
                    if let main = weather[0]["main"] as? String {
                        self.weatherTypeone = main.capitalized
                        print(self.weatherTypeone ?? "No weather type")
                    }
                }

                if let main = dictionary["main"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                    if let currentTemperature = main["temp"] as? Double {
                        let kelvintoFarenheit = (currentTemperature * (9/5) - 459.67)
                        let totalKelvinToFarenheit = Double(round(10 * kelvintoFarenheit/10))
                        self.currentTempone = totalKelvinToFarenheit
                        print(self.currentTempone ?? .nan)

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        completed()
    }
}
```

Is problem with my code or my view controller? Is it something wrong with my constraints?

I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: There are no `print` statements in `updateTodayUI`, so where does the output come from?

Comment: @AndreasOetjen i have add my the code that has the print statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `completed` too early - before the JSON response arrives. You have to call it inside the closure of the `responseJSON` call instead:

```
Alamofire.request(weatherURL).responseJSON { response in
    let result = response.result
    // ...
    completed()
}
```

Comment: I was able to fixed it. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see all of your code to troubleshoot, but you may have a concurrency issue. Try putting the call to `updateTodayUI` inside of `viewDidLoad(_:)` inside of an async block like this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    updateTodayUI()
}
```

You can find more information on dispatch queues and concurrency in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html).